# Is server side CORS protection enough to mitigate CSRF attacks against stateless APIs?

Tags: cookies, csrf, api, threat-mitigation, cors

Assume an Angular SPA application on [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) that works invoking an API over that same domain [www.example.com/api/..](http://www.example.com/api/..).

The Angular app gets a session cookie and sends it in each API call.

The usual CSRF attack would try to execute a script with some API call, such as POST [www.example.com/api/deleteUser](http://www.example.com/api/deleteUser) when the user clicks an evil link [www.evil.com](http://www.evil.com).

The question is: if the API server has a properly configured CORS policy, allowing only [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) as origin, is it enough to mitigate CSRF attacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CORS policy is not sufficient to protect against CSRF attacks in general, but might be in this specific case.

The question is, if the API accepts "simple" request as defined by the CORS specification. These are requests which can be triggered without JavaScript, i.e. by a form upload, embedding an image or similar. In this case the request will be send directly to the server and all what CORS could prevent is that the attacker could **read** the response. This is thus not sufficient to prevent CSRF, since CSRF about **writing** the request and thus executing the action at the server.

If the API instead accepts only non-simple requests (for example by requiring a custom HTTP header) then CORS will be a sufficient protection because in this case only a pre-flight request is needed before the actual request and based on the returned CORS policy from this pre-flight request the actual request will not be executed.

Comment: Steffen, thanks for your answer. If I understood well, If, instead of a cookie, the API server were expecting a custom header (Authorization: Bearer + JWT) and the client had to retrieve it from, let's suppose, the session storage, this scenario wouldn't be vulnerable to CSRF attacks, is this right?

Comment: @codependent: Correct. With a custom header a pre-flight request will be done by the browser to check the CORS policy first.